# Вызов функции при любом срабатывании handler в telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Всем привет, вопрос такого характера: можно ли при вызове любого handler(отправка текста/фото/видео и т.д.) перед его обработкой вызывать функцию(пример: проверка доступа), чтобы прописать это один раз, а не в каждом хендлере? Если такое возможно - расскажите как. Заранее спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй как-то так:

```
# Функция, которая будет вызываться при срабатывании хандлера
def function(message):
    print("Я работаю!")

@bot.message_handler(func=function)
def handle_all_messages(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Это обработчик всех сообщений")
```